# How to configure htop to display the complete command line?

Tags: htop

It there a way to display the complete command line in `htop` (e.g. in multiple lines or with a moving banner). With the default setting where only one line is displayed it isn't possible to distungish all processes, e.g. different `java` programs (because class or jar argument follows a bunch of arguments) or programs with long absolute path of binaries.

Omitting the full absolute path in favour of only the binary would be a compromise where distinction would not be optimal, but better in some cases.

I checked out the settings and the manpage and didn't find an option suitable in my understanding.

Comment: Something like this `for p in $(pidof java); do echo $p:; cat /proc/$p/cmdline| xargs -0 echo; done |less` to inspect pids commandline?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just press the <kbd>w</kbd> key.

From the help available with <kbd>F1</kbd>:

> w: wrap process command in multiple lines

Comment: cool tips, only works with more recent version of htop (ubuntu 20.04's repo version not included)

Answer (score 47):

As far as I know, the only way to show the full command line is to scroll right with the arrow keys or to use a terminal with a small font.

*EDIT* ([thanks to @LangeHaare](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158839/how-to-configure-htop-to-display-the-complete-command-line/158841?noredirect=1#comment725941_158841)): You can use Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E to jump to the beginning and end the command line.

Comment: Do you know whether there's a way to jump to the end and back to the beginning of the command line? Dealing with `java` command lines containing the complete classpath can lead up to > 2000 signs easily...

Comment: @Karl To the right end? or down end?

Comment: @tachomi The right end (and left end, i.e. the view right after start)

Comment: @KarlRichter you can use CTRL+A and CTRL+E to go to start and end of the scrolling

Comment: There is a feature request but it has been refused: https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/233

Answer (score 6):

ctrl+f and use arrow key to move left and right.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options of `htop` which do not wrap the line, but at least reduce the content are:

- `p`: Show full paths to running programs, where applicable. (This is a toggle key.)
- `m`: Merge exe, comm and cmdline, where applicable. (This is a toggle key.)

With this we can move from, in iOS and Chrome for example:

`/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome` -> `Google Chrome`

More info at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html