# how to make the htop wrap command line

Tags: htop

Now I am using htop to show the process of my server, but I face a problem that when the command is very long, I just see part of the command and I did not know the full information of the process, is it possible to make the htop show full of the command? if the command too long , just wrap the output.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure htop to display the complete command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158839/how-to-configure-htop-to-display-the-complete-command-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t think you can make `htop` wrap long commands in the process list, but you can select a single process and see its full command line, wrapped, by pressing <kbd>w</kbd>.

You can also scroll right and left to see different parts of the display, with <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You already had it enabled, but for other people searching for this, a couple of options of `htop` which do not wrap the line, but at least reduce the content are:

- `p`: Show full paths to running programs, where applicable. (This is a toggle key.)
- `m`: Merge exe, comm and cmdline, where applicable. (This is a toggle key.)

With this we can move from, in iOS and Chrome for example:

`/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome` -> `Google Chrome`

More info at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html